# Proper way of formatting date/time for MySQL and for View vice versa

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, backbone.js

I use backbone with Laravel.

I have several fields in a form with date and time `('dd-mm-yyyy', 'hh:mm')`.

When I want to save the form I use my own function to convert it for MySQL `('yyyy-mm-dd', 'H:i:s')` via `date()` which I added to `save()` in Laravel Model Class.

But vice versa is harder because there is no single function in Laravel for data output.
`find()`, `findOrNew()`, `findOrFail()`, ... - there are in different classes so I cant use single place to add the formatting function.

In this case I even tried to format date in frontend which seems bad practice.

So what way should I use?
Is there any another way to format this date/time?

Comment: The **ONLY** directly supported string format for dates/datetimes in mysql is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. if you're not using that format, then you'll have to convert with [str_to_date()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and/or store your "dates" in text-based field types (e.g. char/varchar).

Comment: I would definitely NOT recommend storing dates in text-based fields.

Answer (score 1):

If the programming environment you are using expects (or can handle) date strings in a certain format, you could just use MySQL functions to construct the string as needed, such as [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

I would not recommend using these functions to convert your date fields to programming environment format in `WHERE`, `ON`, or `HAVING` clauses though. For one, it would then be using string comparison, for another (and more importantly) it defeats any indexing benefits you might have for those fields.